# images and text of a flexbox item overlapping absolute positioned div (tooltip)

Tags: css, overlapping

I'm using `display: flex` to create panels for my upgrade items. The code looks something like this, I tried to re-create it as best as I could: [fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/53obzvft/32/)
. Now I don't understand why are the images overlapping into the tooltip (hover over elements for tooltip to appear). This is very strange, I thought it was because of `display: flex`, so I tried doing the same thing using grid, no luck. The tooltip has to be `position: absolute`, especially because I'm planning on adding some javascript so the tooltip box follows the cursor. What is causing this kind of behavior? I'm thinking there's something to do with flexbox/grid and absolute positioning, but I'm not very good at css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a z-index value to the .tooltip class.

```css
*
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p
{
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: normal;
}
img
{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Upgrade wrapper & body */
#upgrades {
  height:100%;

  box-shadow:0 0 16px 4px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.upgrade {
  display: flex;

  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;

  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.upgrade-img {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
.upgrade-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: 100%;

  padding: 0.5em;
}

/* Upgrade Hover Effects */
.upgrade:hover {box-shadow: 0 0 8px 2px rgb(0, 204, 255);}
.upgrade:hover .tooltip {display: initial;}

/* Tooltip */
.tooltip {
  display: none;

  width: 256px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 64px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100; /* <------- ADDED Z-INDEX */

  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 1px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="upgrade">
  <div class="upgrade-img">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/64x64">
    <div class="tooltip">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ea sequi recusandae commodi necessitatibus voluptatum, labore libero quasi quos veniam eveniet laborum aspernatur harum iusto, provident itaque hic laboriosam unde!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="upgrade-body">
    <p>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/24x24">
      100 (dmg)
    </p>
    <p>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/24x24">
      500 (cost)
    </p>
  </div>
</div><div class="upgrade">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/64x64">
    <div class="tooltip">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ea sequi recusandae commodi necessitatibus voluptatum, labore libero quasi quos veniam eveniet laborum aspernatur harum iusto, provident itaque hic laboriosam unde!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/24x24">
      100 (dmg)
    </p>
    <p>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/24x24">
      500 (cost)
    </p>
  </div>
</div><div class="upgrade">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/64x64">
    <div class="tooltip">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam ea sequi recusandae commodi necessitatibus voluptatum, labore libero quasi quos veniam eveniet laborum aspernatur harum iusto, provident itaque hic laboriosam unde!
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <p>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/24x24">
      100 (dmg)
    </p>
    <p>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/24x24">
      500 (cost)
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I haven't had time to be @ the computer. I forgot to mention that I have already tried z-index before, with no luck. But right now, it's working. I have no idea why it didn't work in the first place, and I'm super confused right now. Might be because I had z-index: 0 inside the "* {}". Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I am facing same issue but I am using z-index for position relative element.